# CSS transitions for layout changes (as other elements are revealed in the DOM)?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When a new block is displayed, other blocks may move around the page.

Is it possible to use CSS transitions to animate the movement of a block, when another block is displayed?

Initial state:

[image]

Subsequent state:

[image]

Eg:

- Initially only the blue block is displayed
- The green block is displayed, pushing the blue block down
- I would like the blue block to animate moving to its new position

[Obligatory JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRB5j/)

**Is it possible to animate the blue block moving to its new position?** I have CSS `transition` set on both the blocks and their parents.

Or (as I'm beginning to suspect) are CSS transitions only for actual CSS changes, **not the subsequent effects of those CSS changes**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make layout changes with CSS3 as you can animate margin, position, width, height...

The problem is triggering those layout changes. but you can use help from JS to trigger those animations via a class change.

For your example, you could do this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BRB5j/5/)**

*CSS :*

```
.item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.first {
    margin-top:-170px;
}
```

*JS :*

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('.first').classList.remove("first");
}, 2 * 1000)
```

Comment: Ah, so, rather than use `display`, use `margin` to display something offscreen, then animate changing that margin? Makes sense.

Comment: @mikemaccana for your example it works but for other situations, you can use `position` with `top/left...`

Comment: What if your elements are not positioned with absolute values, but with simple layout, like block elements below each other? Can you animate the layout's change when an element added or removed in the middle of the list of block elements? This is needed when you can't guarantee that your elements will be of a predetermined size.

Answer (score 6):

There is a technique for this called FLIP (First, Last, Invert, Play) and a library implementing it called [Flipping.js](https://github.com/davidkpiano/flipping). It is described in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/animating-layouts-with-the-flip-technique/).